# Case within a Select returning "missing expression ORA-00905"

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

this is my first post here, I'd like to ask for help on a theoretically simple query.

The current query I'm creating is to try and generate a random number, which will be identified as even or odd. Depending on that value, it should print either "M" as even, or "W" as odd. Though when I try using a case inside the select, I'm getting the "missing keyword" error. This is my following code:

```
select 
  case 
    when mod(round(dbms_random.value(1,100)),2) = 0 then dbms_output.put_line('M');
    when mod(round(dbms_random.value(1,100)),2) = 1 then dbms_output.put_line('W');
  end  
from dual
```

I've tried checking the website for similar problems, and while I've found similar problems and people getting the solution correctly, I don't quite know what I'm missing here. When I run the select alone, I get the even or odd number I want to get, but not when I try to print out a result.

Comment: `dbms_output.put_line` is a procedure you can call from PL/SQL only, it cannot be called from within a SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT statement cannot PRINT, it can only RETURN something.

You may use query like

```
select
  v,
  case when mod(v, 2) = 0 then 'M' else 'W' end l
from
  (select round(dbms_random.value(1, 100)) v from dual)
```

and process it's result as you wish (print, for example).

Comment: Thanks! Coming back after a long pause to programming, still relearning some old stuff

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to embed dbms_output in a query?  Just write:

```
select 
  case 
    when mod(round(dbms_random.value(1,100)),2) = 0 then 'M'
    when mod(round(dbms_random.value(1,100)),2) = 1 then 'W'
  end  
from dual
```

Also you know, since you are calling dbms_random two different times, you get two different values in the same query.  If you want one value to be compared, then use a WITH clause

```
with rand_value as
( select round(dbms_random.value(1,100)) val from dual
)
select 
  case 
    when mod(val,2) = 0 then 'M'
    when mod(val,2) = 1 then 'W'
  end  
from rand_value
```

Comment: The reason would be lack of practice. But now it works due to the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because of the semicolons.

Also you are calling the random function twice and thus get two different random values. I would use IF-THEN-ELSE instead of a SELECT statement, since the latter one cannot print.

```
IF mod(round(dbms_random.value(1,100)),2) = 0 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('M');
ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('W');
END IF;
```

Comment: Currently I'm supposed to use this select in a simple way, but I'll try using it with an IF-ELSE as well, thanks!